# ComponentWillRecieveProps was replaced with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the reasons behind the use of getDerivedStateFromProps and why componentWillRecieveProps was deprecated. I found [the article](https://itzone.com.vn/en/article/replace-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-in-react/) which provides some reasons. It says that one of the reasons componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated is that it is synchronous and it can be a problem if we try using asynchronous code in it. **Is it bacause componentWillRecieveProps has to wait until the finish of the asynchronous code in it and block rendering?** Secondly, the article says that getDerivedStateFromProps is asynchronous and static meaning we cannot use this, in turn, this.setState. **Since getDerivedStateFromProps is asynchronous, meaning not blocking, why we cannot use api calls or setState in it?**

Comment: I'd say the article is very badly written and it's not accurate either so look at other documentations.

Comment: @technophyle, in that case, can you please kindly explain the two questions BOLDED above?)) I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @technophyle, pls I have been looking for the information for several days 

Comment: I think you can read the official deprecation notes of `componentWillReceiveProps` and they have pretty good explanation. But, the question is, why are you worried about them because both `componentWillReceiveProps` and `getDerivedStateFromProps` are legacy APIs.